# Magento 2 CSS is not coming merged

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css, resources, merge-css

I have enabled merging for javascript and css from my magento 2 store admin panel. But I can still see all the css coming unmerged in my view source. Javascript merge is working fine and coming merged. Any help here would be appreciated.

I have already set magento to production mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did u run setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy commands after enabling merging in Admin?

Comment: Yes. multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. A Third part plugin css was creating the issue. It was not getting minified as well. Commenting it from the xml did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My first port of call would be to delete `pub/static/frontend/` and `var/view_preprocessed` and then clear all caches (Magento and browser cache).

Answer (score 0):

Delete pub/static/ and var/view_preprocessed manually and then run content:deploy command.

It should work.

Note: Make sure you are on **Production** mode.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deleting `pub/static`, doing so will remove `.htaccess` which can cause issues.

Comment: Yes. You have to keep .htaccess and remove other content.